# Script not working in a Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, button

I have been dealing with this issue and is a very stupid question but I really don't understand why my JavaScript functions never execute when I press the buttons I have tried everything please help thanks!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function validateForm()
  {
  var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($arr ); ?>;
  var counter= <?php echo json_encode($i ); ?>;
  var productId;
  var productQty;
  confirm(productId + " can not be empty");

   for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    productQty = jArray[1][i];
    productId= jArray[0][i];

     if (document.getElementById("register").elements.namedItem("productId").value !== productQty) {
  confirm(productId + " can not be empty");

     }
   }
 }

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction1() {
   alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
  }
</script>

 </head>
 >
 <body>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

   <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<?php

  $code1 ="";
  $exeption="";
  $s="";
  session_start(); 
  $arr=array();

  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','customer_service_experts');

   if (!$con) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
   }

    $empId= $_SESSION['eId'];
    $sql2= "SELECT locationId FROM location_user where empId='".$empId."' and active ='1'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
           $code1 = $row["locationId"];
        }

    mysqli_select_db($con,"customer_service_experts");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM location_product where productLocation=$code1";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


    echo "

      <form  action='productInventoryEmp.php' method='POST' id='register'>
    <div class='form-group col-md-5'>

       ";


      $i=0;

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $arr[1][$i]=$row['productQty'];
        $arr[0][$i]=$row['productId'];
        $sql1="SELECT productName FROM product where productId='".$row['productId'] ."' limit 1 ";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

        if($result1!=false){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
            $code = $row["productName"];
             echo " <div class='input-prepend'>";
             echo "<span class='add-on' >".$code."</span>";
            }

             echo "<input type='number' min='0' step='1' data-bind='value:replyNumber' class='span2' id=" . $row['productId'] . "/>";
              echo "</div>";
        }else {
              $s="1";
                $exeption="There are no Products for  in this location!";
        }
     echo "<br>"; 
     echo "<br>";                
     $i++;                
  }
    $_SESSION['ArrayCount']=$i; //counter
    $_SESSION['ArrayProduct']=$arr; // ID Product y Qty

   if ($s=="1") {
    echo $exeption;
   }
?>

 </div>

 <div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="comment">Note:</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"    onclick="validateForm()">Cancel</button>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onsubmit="myFunction1()">Save and Start Shift</button>

 </div>
 </form>

<?php
 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: You're echoing `json_encode($arr)` and `json_encode($i)` at the beginning of the script, but you're not setting the variables until later in the script.

Comment: not that i know about i just want to use my function the alert one but it doesn't display

Comment: What do you mean? When you open the console, either you see errors or you don't.

Comment: You also do `confirm(productId + "can not be empty")` before you set `ProductId`. What's the point of that?

Comment: im using sublime text 2

Comment: because i was testing the funtion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88070/discussion-between-ifrahim-hernandez-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons submit the form. That's why your functions never execute.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="validateForm()">Cancel</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="myFunction1()">Save and Start Shift</button>
```

Then set id to your form

```
<form id="myform" action="..">
```

And in the end of your functions, if you want to submit the form, set

```
$('#myform').submit();
```

And don't forget to include jquery library.
Hope it works!

Comment: where do i get the jquery library?

Comment: $('#myform').submit(); - this works with jquery library and you need to include it in your html 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: try to move the scripts just before closing body tag

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"    onclick="validateForm()">Cancel</button

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onsubmit="myFunction1()">Save and Start Shift</button>
```

To this:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default"    onclick="validateForm()" >Cancel

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="Save">Save and Start Shift
```

In your script:

```
 $('#Save').on('click', function(){
   myFunction1(); //your function
 });
```